# Delete operation using javascript, but this code is not working

Tags: javascript

This is code to perform the delete operation. The four images appear, but the alert box for delete operation is not appearing by giving the onload functionality. Please guide me...here is the code.

```
// script for deletedelete operation  

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('a.delete').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            imageID = $(this).closest('.image')[0].id;
            alert('Now deleting "'+imageID+'"');
            $(this).closest('.image')
                .fadeTo(300,0,function(){
                    $(this)
                        .animate({width:0},200,function(){
                            $(this)
                                .remove();
                        });
                });
        });

    });
```

HTML

```
//four images being given with delete link


 <div id="container">
        <div class="image" id="image1" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract);">
            <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
        <div class="image" id="image2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food);">
            <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
        <div class="image" id="image3" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people);">
            <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
        <div class="image" id="image4" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics);">
            <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Its deleting when i click each delete link. What was your problem?

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A5u43/24/)

Comment: yes even i tried its working perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/rJ5nw/

Comment: in which browser/version are you testing it, @Shruthi?

Comment: I tried opening in Chrome26, mozilla20 and IE10....but, yes even now its not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works ok.... Let me take a shot here . You have probably not included the Jquery file in your code???

Have you included this tag

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A5u43/25/) is just your code copy pasted. Not one change

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="image" id="image1" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract);">
        <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
    </div>
    <div class="image" id="image2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food);">
        <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
    </div>
    <div class="image" id="image3" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people);">
        <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
    </div>
    <div class="image" id="image4" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics);">
        <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('a.delete').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        imageID = $(this).closest('.image')[0].id;
        alert('Now deleting "'+imageID+'"');
        $(this).closest('.image')
            .fadeTo(300,0,function(){
                $(this)
                    .animate({width:0},200,function(){
                        $(this)
                            .remove();
                    });
            });
    });
```

Comment: Did you try the fiddle. its your code only. have you tried on any other machine?

Comment: Im sure there is something you are not showing. Edit your question and Copy paste the entire contents of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine...If you didn't include Jquery file,include it..

< script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">

< /script>

< script>
$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('a.delete').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    imageID = $(this).closest('.image')[0].id;
    alert('Now deleting "'+imageID+'"');
    $(this).closest('.image')
        .fadeTo(300,0,function(){
            $(this)
                .animate({width:0},200,function(){
                    $(this)
                        .remove();
                });
        });
});
```

});

< /script>

Comment: Your answer does not add anything new to the post. Im sorry for being brutally honest but in SO, these are the rules.

Comment: I just restarted my browser and tried...thanks that it is working fine now!!!! The same code.....

Comment: I want this code on the thumbnails that I add. I am adding images to my gallery as thumbnails, and want to incorporate the delete operation as well. This code does not work. Help me out...                                                               // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<a href="#" class="delete" onclick="Delete();">Delete<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" width="110" height="150"/></a>'].join('');

Comment: @Shruthi I couldn't understand what you are trying to do.Please clearly explain, so that i can help you ,and also post the code in readable format..

Comment: @AnaMaria If you read my comment ,i told that ,the code is working fine and  suggested her to include jquery file.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Thats what I told her too. Quite sometime before you. Thats why I told you that your answer does not add anything new to the post. Nothing against you personally. Just the way things go around here.